# How to Add Items to Power Nap

Tags: macos, mac, power-nap

Is there a way to add applications/processes to the [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032) function on a Mac? In other words, instead of just the default Time Machine, Mail, etc. you can make it run other applications too. I am running a Mac Mini with OS X Yosemite.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can tell, the answer is no. I can't find any mention of public APIs for developers to leverage Power Nap.

What did you have in mind? You could also put in an [enhancement request](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) at Apple.

Comment: I have in mind some specialized server software that responds to certain requests, processes them, and sends them back.